# Complex layout(Word like) report which includes text blocks , tables , charts

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, reportviewer

Is SSRS a right tool to build Complex's layout(Word like) report? Report supposed to be around 100 pages and contains text blocks(static and dynamic), tables, charts. Main idea it should be build from database and should be ready for use without additional editing.
Thanks.

Comment: You seems to be looking for something like Devexpress' Snap (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11373).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing the intricate details of the project. However, based on my experience, SSRS is a very capable tool and I've been able to do some very complex reporting using it.  Every product has it's limitations, at more often then not there are creative ways to overcome those limitations.

I've seen SSRS be used to generating standardized letters, check stocks and even database driven financial disclaimer pages with images.  I can't be 100% certain SSRS will meet your every need, but I'm certain it will come very close, based on your brief description.